# Implement nicely styled scroll bars, and retain native functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the library: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-nicescroll/downloads/detail?name=jquery.nicescroll.340.zip&can=2&q=

Although I seem to be able to use events like jQuery's `scrollLeft` and the likes, nicescroll breaks the middle click and scroll functionality, which in itself is not so bad, but indicates that other unknown behaviours out there might also be broken.

Is there any library/method for implementing nice scroll bars, but with native functionality?

Comment: Depending on browser compat., you can use CSS styles.

Comment: The native functionality still exists, you just have to target the correct element because the element that normally scrolls is no longer the one scrolling.

Comment: the usual scroll functions do work with nicescroll

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head

```
var MIDDLE_CLICK = 2;
var clicking = [];
var moveInterval = undefined;
var lastY = undefined;

$("#nicely_scrolled_element").mousedown(function(e){

  clicking[e.which] = true
  startY = lastY = e.pageY;

  // default behavior is every so often scroll the page
  // we base it on how far they were last from the start
  moveInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $el = $('#nicely_scrolled_element');
    $el.scrollTop($el.scrollTop() + lastY - startY);
  }, 500);
})

// they may mouse up elsewhere so we use window this time
$(window).mouseup(function(e){
  clicking[e.which] = false
  clearInterval(moveInterval);
})

// remember where they moved to
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
  if(clicking[MIDDLE_CLICK]){
    lastY = e.pageY;
  }
})
```

this is untested i just wrote it out.  it should work?